# Operator overloading and iterator confusion

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, operator-overloading

I use this code to find the point of a box (`g`) furthest in the direction `d` 
    typedef vector_t point_t;

```
std::vector<point_t> corners = g.getAllCorners();
coordinate_type last_val = 0;

std::vector<point_t>::const_iterator it = corners.begin();
point_t last_max = *it;

do
{
    coordinate_type new_val = dot_product( *it, d );
    if( new_val > last_val )
    {
        last_val = new_val;
        last_max = *it;
    }
}
while( it != corners.end() );

return last_max;
```

I also have a template operator overload for the operator `!=` for the class `vector_t` which is in the namespace `point`.

```
namespace point
{
    template 
    <
        typename lhs_vector3d_impl, 
        typename rhs_vector3d_impl
    >
    bool operator!=( const typename lhs_vector3d_impl& lhs, const typename rhs_vector3d_impl& rhs )
    {
        return binary_operator_not_equal<lhs_vector3d_impl, rhs_vector3d_impl>::apply( lhs, rhs );
    }
};
```

The overload works fine in most cases but when I use with iterators  (i.e. `it != corners.end()`) it breaks down since I did not intend this function in that case.
I can tell it's because of the template parameters resolution going wrong but i don't know why:

```
lhs_vector3d_impl=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<legend::geometry::point::Carray_Vector3d<int32_t>>>>,
rhs_vector3d_impl=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<legend::geometry::point::Carray_Vector3d<int32_t>>>>
```

I understand the wrong functions get called but I don’t understand why…

So basically my question is how comme iterator comparaison gets resolved with my function instead of an operator in the std namespace and how can I prevent this function from being used.

Note 1: I am beginning with template so I may be doing something very wrong without knowing, if so please kindly tell.

Note 2: this code is used mainly for academic purposes so I really want to do most of it by hand.

Note 3: using Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler

Comment: (A) You probably wrote `using namespace point` so everything sees that overload.  (B) That overload is `template<class A, class B> bool operator(const A&,const B&)`, which matches all types.  Don't use a template here.  There are workarounds but they're confusing.

Comment: Even without the `using namespace` it will be picked up via the magic of ADL - not what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why yu need this template function.
But clearly it may have deduced that lhs and rhs type are `iterator` when you only wanted to use it for `point_t`

Two solutions :

1. remove the templates on the operator definition and use point_t as type (so you are sure)
2. remove a using namespace to be sure that he sees the iterator outside of the `namespace point`

Comment: Dereferencing `end()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @dzada shouldn't the default iterator compare be called instead of my "compare value" operator?

Comment: No, the default version should not be called since you explicitely defined a function (though templated) that exactly fits the requirement. As I see it, your template definition is simply too broad, it essentially overwrites _any_ default `operator!=`.

Comment: @cmaster But there's no *default* `operator !=` for user defined objects, like these iterators. There are though overloads provided by the standard library which operate on its iterators and, as long as they are *specific* to their type, the operator shadowing should not occur. I'm not sure what the standard requires to be the default behavior and if MSVC complies to it, but GCC 4.8.1 has no problem selecting the correct version, even when `using namespace std;` is issued. As a workaround for MSVC, please refer to my answer.

Comment: @brunocodutra Usually, iterators are typedefs to some pointer types (because otherwise they would be excrutiatingly slow), and the compiler knows how to compare pointers. Maybe, there are also iterators that are objects, in these cases you are right, but for the broad majority, this definition does shadow the default operators.

Comment: @cmaster I wouldn't go as far as claiming this case to be the vast majority, for contiguous memory may not always be guaranteed in stl containers, but even if so, simply defining `typedef int* iterator; bool operator !=(iterator lhs, iterator rhs);` within the std library would avoid this mess. I doubt very much the best practice would be to rely on the default comparison for pointers to handle iterators which happen to be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need that overloaded operator != as generic as it is, that is taking **any** two arguments, i.e. matching pretty much anything you pass to it, you can avoid it being prefered for the iterators by explicitly calling the standard library version:

```
std::operator !=(it, corners.end())
```